# Is there any limitation of data size into the index of ferret (Ruby equivalent for Apache Lucene)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, indexing, lucene, ferret

We've deployed Ferret into our Ruby on Rails web platform 2 years ago and the indexing tools is still working very well: today we managed +30 000 000 entries into the index for English and French words (& phrases) only and every search is working incredibly fast in production.

Our target is now to deploy 30 new languages, ie to multiply this number max by 20 to 30 (600 000 000 entries). Do you think this may have any impact in performance to use Ferret ?
Should we split the data index by language or keep a unique one to manage all idioma ? (We currently always specify the language but this is'nt a very important search criteria)

I searched the question into the Ferret [great] tutorial without success. https://github.com/xing/ferret/blob/master/TUTORIAL